# Ambiguous time error pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
df['first_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_timestamp']).dt.tz_localize('US/Central', ambiguous='infer')
df['second_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['second_timestamp']).dt.tz_localize('US/Central', ambiguous='infer')
```

AmbiguousTimeError: 2014-11-02 01:02:14

These timestamps are from a csv file which doesn't include the time zone. I want to add the time zone before I load it into my database though, if possible. Is there something I did wrong with the ambiguous part of that code? I am still getting an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This datetime exists twice in central time, e.g. see [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/minnesota?year=2014):

> Nov 2, 2014 - Daylight Saving Time Ended
>   When local daylight time was about to reach
>   Sunday, November 2, 2014, 2:00:00 am clocks were turned backward 1 hour to
>   Sunday, November 2, 2014, 1:00:00 am local standard time instead
>   Sunrise and sunset was about 1 hour earlier on Nov 2, 2014 than the day   before. There was more light in the morning.

If these are actually UTC, you should localize from UTC:

```
In [11]: pd.Series([pd.Timestamp("2014-11-02 01:02:14 UTC")]).dt.tz_convert('US/Central')
Out[11]:
0   2014-11-01 20:02:14-05:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Central]
```

or pass True to the ambiguous flag (rather than `'infer'`) to just pick one:

```
In [12]: pd.Series([pd.Timestamp("2014-11-02 01:02:14")]).dt.tz_localize('US/Central', ambiguous=True)
Out[12]:
0   2014-11-02 01:02:14-05:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Central]
```

Comment: The actual data is (or should be) in Central time, so I will not be able to localize from UTC. By placing True, this will add the time zone for those few rows which have issues? Hm, I suppose that could work - I doubt it matters. The other option I was playing around with was adding another column called 'utc_offset' with '%z', but ambiguous='NaT' so if there is an issue, the utc_offset column is blank.

Comment: @trench the point is at these times you don't know the actual time (since the timezone at that time _is_ ambigious), most likely the best you can do is pick one! :)